# DroidExplorer won't open after a few runs

Tags: windows, droid-explorer

I have faced this issue over three times now.

I reinstall Windows, use Droid Explorer a couple of times and after about 10 uses, Droid Explorer stops working.

So the issue is Droid Explorer crashes after trying to connect to the device.
This the last message I see:

[image: last screen]

After that it just closes, nothing happens.

Here's the log:
https://pastebin.com/fULc333k
(Sorry, but if I post the log here it's causing some formatting issues.)

Today afternoon, I reinstalled Windows 10 x64 Build 17134.1 (that's the April 2018 update), installed Droid Explorer, used it about 5 times.
Stopped working after that.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Could you add the details of the phone you're trying to connect to and the steps you follow with Droid Explorer there?

Comment: It is a Nexus 6P running Android 8.1.0 (LineageOS 15.1). Anyways, the issue has been solved, thanks to camalot (the developer of DroidExplorer). https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues/66

Comment: In that case, please answer your own question below, to help out future visitors.

Comment: I did, it's in the link I posted. Anyways, I will put it here as well. Delete the folder C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\DroidExplorer. All credits to camalot, the developer of Droid Explorer.